# Take the text of header tags one by one

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I need to do is take the text of header tags one by one when you press the key 'h'. This is my code,

```
var currentHeader;
currentHeader = $(":header").first(); 

$(window).on('keyup', function (e) {
    if (e.which === 72){ //h = 72
        alert(currentHeader.text());
        currentHeader = currentHeader.next(":header");
    } 
});
```

Unfortunately this code not working as expected and no error message passing :'(

> What I need is alert the next header tag text each time I press the
>   'h' key

Comment: Are the `:header` siblings?

Comment: why you are using `:header`? why you dont use `$('header')`?

Comment: @MishelParkour http://api.jquery.com/header-selector/  Because those are not the same thing.

Comment: @Taplar no all the headers in page

Comment: @vimuth `next()` only finds siblings.

Comment: thanks a lot is there any keyword to find next element in dom?

Comment: @vimuth. why you want to list them 1 by 1 when user presses a key? are the headers gonna change on the fly? I mean for example are the content of headers or number of heading tags are gonna change during time user keep pressing a key?

Comment: You need to have a variable that contains all the headers, by which you can use `.index(currentHeader)` to get the index of that header in the result stack, and to go to the next one would be `eq(index +1 )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var headers = $(":header");
var currentHeader = headers.first(); 

$(window).on('keyup', function (e) {
    if (e.which === 72){ //h = 72
        alert(currentHeader.text());
        // go to the next indexed header on the page, after the current header
        currentHeader = headers.eq( headers.index(currentHeader) + 1 );
    } 
});
```

Comment: taplar. that should work. but im thinking of better solution. something like getting all headings in an array and then having kind of a observable and we can call `obs.next()`  whenever user presses a key down. what do you think of my idea? - -because in your solution we should lookup for headers each time user presses a key and it may not be the most optimum way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks so so much bro

Comment: @MishelParkour the only lookup here is the `headers`.  All operations off of headers is internal to javascript operating off of the jQuery result stack.  It's not a DOM operation at that point.

Comment: @Taplar thanks for the info. One last thing and ill give a thumps up. what if the index exceeds the max index? you may want to add an if or something to take care of that right?

Comment: That's true.  Though for that I would want to ask the OP what they would want to happen.  You could stop the logic, or you could wrap back to the first one. @vimuth

Comment: probably something like this: `if(headers.index(currentHeader) + 1<headers.length)`

Comment: okay. so let me know if you made the update and ill check it out. thanks.